# FileWriter not writing all of its contents - how to get around maximum?

Tags: java, csv, io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

After a good amount of time researching the issue, and doing a little counting/debugging on my own, I found out that the max number of characters a FileWriter can contain at once is about 1216. Can anyone help me figure out how to get around this issue?

I'm essentially writing a script in Java to combine two .csv files because I need to put the contents of each file side by side in one .csv file. I'm iterating through and appending the characters, along with commas and new lines, to the file writer. However, all of my outputs are stopping about 80% through the writing process. I'm not getting any errors, but it appears obvious to me now that it is an issue of FileWriter capacity.

If I write what I have then start appending to a new FileWriter, I will lose my spot in the .csv file. I'm not really sure what to do here.

I look forward to feedback. Thank you!!

EDIT - code

The problem is with the mergedWriter.

I've verified that the length of "mainLines[j].size() - 1" is 101, and it is only writing 85ish lines for my outputs. It stops mid-string.

```
for (int k = 0; k < mainLines[j].size() - 1; k++) {
                // All deletions for bottleneck
                if (k != 0) {
                    eachEffWriter.append(mergedFileNum + COMMA + "1," + mainLines[j].get(k)[6] + NEWLINE);
                    efficiencyWriter.append(mergedFileNum + COMMA + "1," + mainLines[j].get(k)[5] + NEWLINE);
                }
                // Write deletionoutput data
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (String str : mainLines[j].get(k)) {
                    builder.append(str);
                    builder.append(COMMA);
                }
                builder.append(COMMA);
                if (k == 0) {
                    builder.append(COMMA);
                }

                for (String str : kingpinLines[j].get(k)) {
                    builder.append(str);
                    builder.append(COMMA);
                }
                mergedWriter.append(builder.toString());
                mergedWriter.append(NEWLINE);
            }
```

Comment: This is nonsense. Post your code.

Comment: Have you called `.close()` on the `FileWriter` after you're done writing?

Comment: Given that I've written a 1.1GB dat file using `FileWriter`, I don't think your assessment that it can only write ~1216 character is correct. Post a code sample so we can diagnose it?

Comment: Agree with Elliot.  Need to show us this before we Bo-leeve

Comment: Edited my post with code.

Comment: Why don't you use Commons CSV?

Comment: I solved it ladies and gents. Getting up and making a sandwich must have cleared my mind. The issue was that I was re-insantiating the mergedWriter 100 times, but I had forgotten to flush/close it each time.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Sorry it turned out to be somewhat of a boneheaded move. I guess that's what happens when you're working with 5 different writers at once, with one of the writers needing to iterate through 100 files.

Comment: @Matt Please remove the question or answer it if you have solved your problem.

Comment: Since [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) doesn't have an `append`, I'll just ask why are you building everything into `String`(s) instead of ***streaming*** to your `File`?

Answer (score 4):

Solved.

I wasn't flushing/closing my writer before re-instantiating it to a new file. I should have either made an array of mergedWriters, or flushed/closed it each time before re-assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `fw.close()` after write system.